# How to specify a ProgrammingError exception

Tags: python, pyodbc

Sometimes I get this error when executing a to_sql() statement

> Exception: ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I know exactly what I'd like to do with this error so I want to catch it, but I can't seem to do so. If I do a catch all, it works, but catching this error specifically hasn't seemed to work. Basically, here's what I've got below.

```
from pyodbc import ProgrammingError
try:
    #code
except ProgrammingError:
    #other code
```

At first when I tried specifying the error, it said ProgrammingError wasn't defined so I just thought I'd give the import a shot, but no luck. I'd rather not do a catch all, how can I specify this exception?

Comment: I would have expected `ProgrammingError` to work.  Can you reproduce the error?  If so, do a `except Exception as ex:` and then `print(type(ex))`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Hey John, sorry to get back to you so late. Here's what I get when doing so ```<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError'>``` sqlalchemy is a library that I'm using. Tried importing ProgrammingError from there, but cannot

Comment: Did you try importing it from `sqlalchemy` or from `sqlalchemy.exc`? The latter works for me. If it doesn't for you, something stranger is going on.